# Upgrading to jQuery 1.7 and changes to the event object

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

Ok this one through me for a loop, but I finally traced it down to changes in the event object parameter on callbacks.  Let me outline the problem:

I recently upgraded to jquery 1.7 from 1.6.2 and noticed some strange things happen.

Most noticeably my jquery-ui (1.8.16) "sortables" began to have some unwanted side-effects:

HTML STRUCTURE

```
<ul id="ulFeatured">
    <li><span class="Title">Item 1</span></li>
    <li><span class="Title">Item 2</span></li>
    <li><span class="Title">Item 3</span></li>
</ul>

<ul id="ulAvailable">
    <li><span class="Title">Item 4</span></li>
    <li><span class="Title">Item 5</span></li>
    <li><span class="Title">Item 6</span></li>
</ul>
```

JQUERY

```
$("#ulFeatured, #ulAvailable").sortable
(
    {
        connectWith: ".connectedSortable",
        receive: function (event, ui)
        {
            console.log(event.target);
        }
    }
).disableSelection();
```

RESULTS

```
1.6.12
<ul id="ulFeatured" class="connectedSortable ui-sortable NoItems" style="">

1.7
<span class="Title">
```

Anyone have any insights into this one?  I would like to use the original functionality of the event.target being the item receiving the item.

Thanks! :)

Comment: In W3C conforming browsers, *event.target* is the element that originally dispatched the event. As far as I can tell, you are putting a listener on the ULs but the click must be on a span. So it seems to me that *event.target* should be the span (but I have no idea what *sortable* is doing, it might be "fixing" the event object and changing the value of the target property).

Comment: "Sortable" is a feature in the jquery UI library which enables the dragging and dropping of elements between UL's.  I am using the built in "receive" event listener to detect items being added to a UL from another.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the jQuery method `.closest()` to find the list that the item belonged to.

```
$("#ulFeatured, #ulAvailable").sortable
(
    {
        connectWith: ".connectedSortable",
        receive: function (event, ui)
        {
            console.log($(event.target).closest('ul'));
        }
    }
).disableSelection();
```

[Working example here](http://jsfiddle.net/5AtL9/)

Comment: That is the exact work around I came up with.  I just was wondering about the change in jquery, or as it would seem, bugfix that has made the event object W3C complaint.