# jquery ui sortable issue with jQuery 1.7.1

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Upgrading to jQuery 1.7 and changes to the event object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8044992/upgrading-to-jquery-1-7-and-changes-to-the-event-object)

all. I'm using Jquery UI and I have a problem with sortable plugin after update jquery version to 1.7.1 (previous was 1.6.4).

I'm using sortable with connectWith option for lists. And a problem is with events:
for example, when start callback is working it receive `event` and `ui`. In 1.6.4 `event.target` was `ul` element, but now it's element I click (inside of `li` element).

What is it? why target is incorrect? what is the reason? Will it be fixed in next versions of jquery ui plugin?

Example you can try on [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/emaxuc/edit#javascript,html)